# How to partition a master table?

Tags: postgresql

Now,am using the postgresql .In our master table nearly 1,000,000 records .we already create the index of this table but it will slightly improve the performance.So we will decide to partition the table.we think it is the right way to increase the performance..

## What I need:

How to partition the table in Postgresql ?
What are the steps am i should follow ?

Comment: Is that 100 thousand or one million?

Comment: this is dependent on your schema and data traffic. u can't get good advice by just saying "we need to partition a million records".

Comment: Why is this tagged for Oracle?

Comment: Generally, partitioning only really makes sense for time-series data, so that you can drop old data cheaply without DELETEs (prevents bloat). In other cases, it's almost always a win to create composite and/or partial indexes specially tuned for your query.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you think you need to partion your table? I would start to find out what the problem is, why your queries are too slow. Start using [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html) to see how a query is executed and what might be the problem. Could you show us the queryplan?

A million records is not that much, unless each record is very large.

Comment: I agree. If the query is already slow with just a million rows, there is some other problem in the system

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

See section "5.9.2. Implementing Partitioning" in POSTGRESQL's help documentation about partitioning: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html

I found this article incredibly informative when it comes to putting together partitioned tables.  I would also agree with everyone else that 1M records should still be fast without a partition.  Your index(es) may not be getting used on your queries but that would be the topic for a separate question.